# How to sum cells in a column if a condition is met in another column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I wasn't entirely sure on how to word this question, but I'll explain my question...
I have a table in a mysql database similar to

```
cust_name | order_date | sales_price
----------+------------+------------
john      | 2013-02-11 | 100
matt      | 2012-02-29 | 50
sam       | 2013-03-13 | 25
tony      | 2013-02-12 | 105
```

I found DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%M') can bring back the month of the date and DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%Y') will do the same for the year.

What I could like to do is query the database to bring back something like

```
year  | month | tot_price
------+------------------
2013  | 02    | 205
2013  | 03    | 25
2012  | 02    | 50
```

Maybe even just bring back values just in 2013.
I had a few attempts similar to this:

```
SET @july := 0;
Select customer,
    case DATE_FORMAT(order_date, '%M')
    when 'july' then @july := @july + 1
end as amount
from mytable
```

but, I got nowhere with it because i realized I don't know how to output a variables value...
So, what should I do to write such a query? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select year(order_date) as order_year,
       month(order_date) as order_month,
       sum(sales_price) as tot_price,
       group_concat(cust_name) as customers_in_month
from mytable
group by order_year, order_month
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fbc36/3/0)

Comment: Thanks juergen! fiddle will definitely help me a lot! :)